# Different outputs for the same thing in python

Tags: python-2.7

```
sr = [12,13,4]
thre = 1

kaju = []

for p in range(len(sr)):
    sr[p] -= thre
    kaju.append(sr)
    print sr

print kaju
```

**Result came out as**:

```
[11, 13, 4]
[11, 12, 4]
[11, 12, 3]
[[11, 12, 3], [11, 12, 3], [11, 12, 3]
```

I don't know why sr and kaju are not same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists are passed by *reference* in Python. So when you are appending `sr` to `kaju`, you are just appending another reference to the same list. Your print statements thus reflect the changes to `sr` upon each iteration, but that `kaju` just contains a bunch of references to the same list.

If you want the elements of `kaju` to reflect the changes on each iteration, you must copy `sr`'s value on each iteration, which can be done with the built-in `list()` function

```
for p in range(len(sr)):
    sr[p] -= thre
    kaju.append(list(sr))
    print sr 

print kaju
```

**Outputs**:

```
[11, 13, 4]
[11, 12, 4]
[11, 12, 3]
[[11, 13, 4], [11, 12, 4], [11, 12, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you append the whole list in `sr` each time you call append. You probably wanted to just append `sr[p]`